# Rotate plane used to find world coordinates

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to find world coordinates from screen coordinates on a `Plane` where `mCamera` is a `PerspectiveCamera`.

```
public Vector3 getWorldCoordinates(float x, float y) {
    // Use an imaginary plane at z=0 to intersect ray
    Plane plane = new Plane();
    plane.set(0, 0, 1, 0);
    Ray ray = mCamera.getPickRay(x, y);
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3();
    Intersector.intersectRayPlane(ray, plane, pos);
    return pos;
}
```

How can I modify this routine to rotate the `Plane` `x` degrees on the X axis before finding the coordinates?

Is there any simple built in libgdx routines used to rotate the plane such as for the `Camera` using `Camera.rotate(Vector3.X, degrees)`?

Comment: Set a Vector3 to 0, 0, 1 and rotate it. Then use that to set your plane.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Can you add it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a Vector3 to the orientation you want and use that to set the Plane. So in your case

```
vector3.set(0, 0, 1);
vector3.rotateX(0.5f); // for example
plane.set(vector3.x, vector3.y, vector3.z, 0);
```

If you are doing this on every frame, you might want to consider instantiating your vector and plane one time in the class constructor and reusing them so you don't occasionally trigger the GC, which can cause stutters.